# ProtectedRoute return blank page in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have the following logic in `App.js`:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import Product from "./components/Product";
import Login from "./components/Login";
import Signup from "./components/Signup";
import ProtectedRoute from "./components/ProtectedRoute";
import { UserAuthContextProvider } from './context/UserAuthContext'

function App(){
    return(
      <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <UserAuthContextProvider>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
            <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />} />
            <Route element={<AuthLayout />}>
              <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
              <Route path="/product" element={<Product />} />
            </Route>
          </Routes>
        </UserAuthContextProvider>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
    );
}

const AuthLayout = ({ children }) => {
  return <ProtectedRoute>{children}</ProtectedRoute>;
};

export default App;
```

ReactJS can load `/login` and `/signup` pages smoothly. The problem happens when the user is logged into the system (Firebase) and tries to access the `/` and `/product` pages.

This is the logic of `ProtectedRoute.js`:

```
import React from "react";
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useUserAuth } from "../context/UserAuthContext";

const ProtectedRoute = ({ children }) => {
  const { user } = useUserAuth();

  console.log("Check user in Private: ", user);
  
  if (!user) {
    return <Navigate to="/login" />;
  }

  return children;
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

Why my protected pages are blank, and how I can solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Outlet`, if you are using `React-v6`. [Outlet Docs](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/outlet).

[Ref Docs](https://medium.com/@dennisivy/creating-protected-routes-with-react-router-v6-2c4bbaf7bc1c)

```
//ProtectedRoute.js
import { Outlet, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

const ProtectedRoute = () => {
  const { user } = useUserAuth();

  console.log("Check user in Private: ", user);
  
  return user ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/login" />;
};
```